# How to turn an entire data frame into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.5, 0.75]}, index=['row1', 'row2'])

>>> df
      col1  col2
row1     1  0.50
row2     2  0.75
```

How can I generate a dictionary with four entries, like

```
dict[(row1, col1)] = 1
dict[(row1, col2)] = 0.5
dict[(row2, col1)] = 2
dict[(row2, col2)] = 0.75
```

i.e., the key is a tuple with first one being the index and the 2nd one being the column name. My data frame is big. So a fast way is going to help a lot.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: your expected result is not valid python or json(like) nor can i make sense of it

Comment: the title of your question is misleading

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has [DataFrame.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

```
d = df.to_dict()

print(d)
{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}

print(d['col1']['row1'])
1
```

To get something like the example you posted, I would implement a specific function to populate the dictionary with a syntax that is close to the one you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
def f(row, col, val):
    global d
    d[row][col] = val #invert row/col if you prefer
    
f('row1', 'col1', 1)
f('row1', 'col2', 0.5)
f('row2', 'col1', 2)
f('row2', 'col2', 0.75)

print(dict(d))
{'row1': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 0.5}, 'row2': {'col1': 2, 'col2': 0.75}}

print(pd.DataFrame(d))
      row1  row2
col1   1.0  2.00
col2   0.5  0.75


print(pd.DataFrame(d).T) #translate the df if you prefer
      col1  col2
row1   1.0  0.50
row2   2.0  0.75
```

But honestly, I would just stick with the standard dictionary and syntax, I don't see any advantage in doing something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the result is not quite what I want. I need to use the dictionary very repeatedly. So I really want to make the syntax as simple as possible.

Comment: Then you are not looking for a dictionary. You need to implement your own class for that.

Comment: @qqzj check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.5, 0.75]}, index=['row1', 'row2'])

df.to_dict()
```